# Convert HTML Report to PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, jqplot

I want convert an HTML report to PDF. I know that there are so many libraries are available for this purpose. But the HTML report contains so many graphs created using Jqplot. I want to include these graphs in the PDF also. If you are familiar with any library which also convert graphs to PDF, please give me the reference.

Comment: I think what you are looking for has not been created yet. Have you considered converting your charts to images and then using a library like http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: i don't see it being possible with out converting the charts to images. or creating then like that in the first place.

Comment: you can press [PrintScreen] then [crtl]+[v] to paste a screen image into the document and convert that to pdf using about any tool. you lose select-able text though, and not all browsers let you paste copied image data...

Answer (score 2):

you can use bullzip pdf printer it creates a virtual pdf printer that can transform your HTML content to a pdf file from the browser:
http://www.bullzip.com/

you can also find a lot of useful tools right there!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Jqplot, but I have successfully converted html pages which contain pie charts from [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) (completely javascript generated) to pdf.

I used `wkhtmltopdf` - it's a commandline tool but there are wrapper classes for php and some others I believe.

I'm sure you could find something applicable with a bit of googling but this looks promising: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf